# Can I bring my family if I get a working visa to Ireland?

Tags: working-visas, family, ireland

If a citizen of the USA gets a working visa to Ireland, can he bring his wife and under 18 children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As provided by the [Citizens Information Board](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/), which gives information on public services and entitlements in Ireland.

> **[Residence rights of family members](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/rights_of_residence_in_ireland/residence_rights_of_family_members.html)**
>
> **Non-EEA citizens**
>
> If you are from outside the EEA or Switzerland, then your right to have family members come to live with you depends on the rules governing your presence in Ireland. At present, there is no legislation governing rights of residence for this group. The description here is of the current administrative arrangements. It is open to you to apply to the Irish Naturalisation and Immigration Service (INIS) for anyone (including a partner) to be allowed join you in Ireland - see 'How to apply.'
>
> Family members are generally spouses, civil partners and children under the age of 18.
>
> **Workers**
>
> If you have a Critical Skills Employment Permit, you may bring your family to live with you in Ireland immediately. Your spouse, civil partner and dependants may then get Dependant/Partner/Spousal Employment Permits.
>
> If you have a General Employment Permit, you may be able to bring your family to live here after you have been legally working here for a year. You also have to be able to show that you will be able to support them. In practice, you need to be earning an income above the limits for Family Income Supplement. Your spouse, civil partner and dependants aged under 18 may apply for a General Employment Permit once they are legally resident in Ireland.